# Assembly ASCII integer being used in comparison

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I have a small assembly program that isn't jumping to a label when I except it to. I suspect that this is due to a comparison between ASCII values and integers.

```
section .bss    
    nvalue: resb 4
    value: resb 4

section .data 

    inputPromptNValue db 'Enter a integer: '
    inputPromptNValueLen equ $-inputPromptNValue

    inputPrompt db 'Enter an integer: '
    inputPromptLen equ $-inputPrompt

    msg db 'msg one', 0xa
    msgLen equ $-caseOneMsg

section .text 
global _start   
_start: 

    ;prompt user
    mov eax, 4      
    mov ebx, 1      
    mov ecx, inputPrompt 
    mov edx, inputPromptLen 
    int 80h 

    ;read and store the user input 
    mov eax, 3      
    mov ebx, 0      
    mov ecx, nvalue 
    mov edx, 5       
    int 80h 

    ;
    mov ecx, nvalue
    or ecx, 0x30
    cmp ecx, 0x1    ; <--- this part isn't working
    je someLabel    ; <--- 

    ;.... more labels 

someLabel:
    ;other instructions here
```

The idea is that based on user input of some integer (0-9), an option will be chosen (a certain label will be jumped to).

When the user inputs a value of "1" I would expect the above label (`someLabel`) to be jumped to. What can I do to get this behavior?

Comment: Comment your code. It would be immediately obvious that `or ecx, 0x30` makes no sense. Also, characters are 1 byte but you are processing 4. Finally, learn to use a debugger.

Comment: `(foo | 0x30) == 1` is always false...  Did you mean to use `'1'` (the ASCII code for `1`) instead of integer `1`?  That OR still makes no sense.

Comment: Yes. My mistake was in part using the integer 1 and not the ASCII code for 1. This is basically my first ever assembly program, so I didn't really pick up on what was going wrong. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The idea is that based on user input of some integer (0-9)

So based on that need, you only need enter one digit at a time. Notice that I specifically used the word *digit* because one or more digits without a fractional portion is still an integer.

```
mov eax, 3      
mov ebx, 0      
mov ecx, nvalue 
mov edx, 1                
int 80h
```

Now your ready to read the value at the memory location nvalue

```
mov cl, [nvalue]
```

It will be in the range 39H -> 30H provided you didn't press some other key. It is a good idea in your program to check for those types of errors. Without doing anything else, your test can be;

```
cmp cl,31H
jz  somelabel
```

or

```
cmp cl,'1'
jz  somelabel
```

or even

```
and cl,0xF
cmp cl, 1
jz  somelabel
```

Each of these scenarios will jump to **somelabel** 
Only use data widths byte, word, dword, qword necessary for the task, but if the contents at memory location nvalues was;

> 32 00 00 00

then

```
mov ecx, [nvalue]
cmp ecx, 32H

... even ...

cmp ecx, '2'
```

Would still work, but you'd be unnecessarily forcing assembler to produce larger code.

Even though ECX is considered a general purpose register, but has additional functionality, so unless there is a reason, most often it is better to use AL AX or EAX for computations and comparisons.